# Webapp2: Initialize the response object with values

Tags: python, http-headers, webapp2

Is there any way to initialize the `response` object with certain values so that other methods that use the `response` object don't have to re-declare those values?

E.g. 
**This is what I currently have to do:**

```
class TodoHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    """Handle all the actions of the API"""

    def options(self):
        """Need to re-declare common headers in each method"""
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
        self.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
        self.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'OPTIONS'


    def post(self):
        """Need to re-declare common headers in each method"""
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
        self.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
        self.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST'

        new_title = json.loads(self.request.body).get('title')
        self.response.write('Successfully added new todo')
```

**This is what I'd like to create:**

```
class TodoHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    """Handle all the actions of the API"""

    def initialize():
        # Set response headers to handle CORS
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
        self.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'

    def options(self):
        """Response already initialized, so I only have to declare what I need for this method"""

        self.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'OPTIONS'


    def post(self):
        """Response already initialized, so I only have to declare what I need for this method"""

        self.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST'

        new_title = json.loads(self.request.body).get('title')
        self.response.write('Successfully added new todo')
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally more than one class handler would need to share some common methods and response values in which case you would implement your own `RequestHandler` class which inherits from `webapp2.RequestHandler`. All your subsequent route/request handlers would then inherit from the newly created custom `RequestHandler`:

```
class CustomApiRequestHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def render_api_json(self, obj):
        self.response.content_type = 'application/json'
        self.response.headers.add_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        self.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
        self.response.write(json.encode((self.to_json(obj))))


class TodoHandler(CustomApiRequestHandler):
    def options(self):
        """Response already initialized, so I only have to declare what I need for this method"""
        self.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'OPTIONS'
        return self.render_api_json(...)

    def post(self):
        """Response already initialized, so I only have to declare what I need for this method"""
        self.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST'
        return self.render_api_json(...)
```

Note that if all or many `options`/`post` methods require common headers/tasks/etc you could also implement them in your custom `RequestHandler` as well and then call `super()` in the beginning of your methods.